$sort in aggregate command have inconsistent output when using golang with mongo driver
I have created a endpoint to query all users in a certain school. Every user will have a list of his favorite other user and their favorite point. The query result will be sorted descending based on "favorite" point which is determined by the user who wants to query, which means every query will be sorted uniquely to that person.
The favorite user will be stored in this field
SendStatistic map[primitive.ObjectID]int `json:"send_statistic" bson:"send_statistic"`

Which is located in user model
type User struct {
    ID            primitive.ObjectID         `json:"_id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    UserID        string                     `json:"user_id,omitempty" bson:"user_id,omitempty"`
    Role          string                     `json:"role,omitempty" bson:"role,omitempty" validate:"required"`
    Email         string                     `json:"email,omitempty" bson:"email,omitempty" validate:"required,email"`
    Firstname     string                     `json:"firstname,omitempty" bson:"firstname,omitempty" validate:"required"`
    Lastname      string                     `json:"lastname,omitempty" bson:"lastname,omitempty" validate:"required"`
    Classroom     string                     `json:"classroom,omitempty" bson:"classroom,omitempty"`
    Number        int                        `json:"number,omitempty" bson:"number,omitempty" validate:"required,number"`
    SchoolID      primitive.ObjectID         `json:"school_id,omitempty" bson:"school_id,omitempty"`
    Status        string                     `json:"status,omitempty" bson:"status,omitempty"`
    SendStatistic map[primitive.ObjectID]int `json:"send_statistic" bson:"send_statistic"`bson:"language,omitempty"`
    Value         int                        `json:"value,omitempty" bson:"value,omitempty"`

    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"created_at,omitempty" bson:"created_at,omitempty"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"updated_at,omitempty" bson:"updated_at,omitempty"`
}

Knowing that, I create a aggregate pipeline that does this in order:

remove unwanted user (the user who is not in the school for example, using $match)
create field "index" that will determine if this user is in the favorite list of the user who wants to query (using $set alongside with $indexOfArray)
if the user is in the favorite list (index != -1), create field "value" which is the favorite point, using $set and $cond
sort all records by value (descending), then sort by firstname and lastname

The code goes like this
func (r *UserRepository) GetUsers(user *model.User, role string, classroom string) (*[]model.User, error) {
    var users []model.User
    collection := r.db.Database("activity").Collection("users")

    queryOptions := bson.M{"school_id": user.SchoolID}
    if role != "" {
        queryOptions["role"] = role
    }
    if classroom != "" {
        queryOptions["classroom"] = classroom
    }

    favoriteUserIdList := bson.A{}
    favoriteUserValueList := bson.A{}

    for key, value := range user.SendStatistic {
        favoriteUserIdList = append(favoriteUserIdList, key)
        favoriteUserValueList = append(favoriteUserValueList, value)
    }

    o1 := bson.M{
        "$match": queryOptions,
    }

    o2 := bson.M{
        "$set": bson.M{
            "index": bson.M{
                "$indexOfArray": bson.A{
                    favoriteUserIdList, "$_id",
                },
            },
        },
    }

    o3 := bson.M{
        "$set": bson.M{
            "value": bson.M{
                "$cond": bson.A{
                    bson.M{"$ne": bson.A{"$index", -1}},
                    bson.M{"$arrayElemAt": bson.A{favoriteUserValueList, "$index"}},
                    -1,
                },
            },
        },
    }

    o4 := bson.M{
        "$sort": bson.M{
            "value":     -1,
            "firstname": 1,
            "lastname":  1,
        },
    }

    argregateCommand := bson.A{o1, o2, o3, o4}

    pipe, err := collection.Aggregate(context.TODO(), argregateCommand)
    pipe.All(context.TODO(), &users)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &users, nil

}

It does work well, sometimes of course. The query result in postman said that sometimes the result looks like this
{
            "_id": "66a52b55c89915bdc59998e6",
            "user_id": "1945669",
            "role": "TCH",
            "email": "taniaruecker@kutch.io",
            "firstname": "Rozella",
            "lastname": "Bashirian",
            "classroom": "6/1",
            "number": 90,
            "school_id": "66a15336180937847c68410e",
            "send_statistic": {},
            "language": "ENG",
            "value": 1,
            "device": null,
            "notification": null,
            "created_at": "2024-07-27T17:16:05.019Z",
            "updated_at": "2024-07-27T17:16:05.019Z"
        },
        {
            "_id": "66a79886b463e7c7229e8f06",
            "user_id": "833095",
            "role": "STD",
            "email": "dedrickstiedemann@white.biz",
            "firstname": "Alva",
            "lastname": "Nolan",
            "classroom": "1/6",
            "number": 10,
            "school_id": "66a15336180937847c68410e",
            "send_statistic": {},
            "language": "ENG",
            "value": -1,
            "device": null,
            "notification": null,
            "created_at": "2024-07-29T13:26:30.813Z",
            "updated_at": "2024-07-29T13:26:30.813Z"
        },
.
.
.

Which is the correct order (this user ONLY have favorite point for 66a52b55c89915bdc59998e6 as 1)
But sometimes the result looks like this

{
            "_id": "66a52b55c89915bdc59998e5",
            "user_id": "9607586",
            "role": "TCH",
            "email": "reyboyle@klocko.net",
            "firstname": "Peggie",
            "lastname": "Ankunding",
            "classroom": "5/5",
            "number": 74,
            "school_id": "66a15336180937847c68410e",
            "send_statistic": {},
            "language": "ENG",
            "value": -1,
            "device": null,
            "notification": null,
            "created_at": "2024-07-27T17:16:05.018Z",
            "updated_at": "2024-07-27T17:16:05.018Z"
        },
        {
            "_id": "66a79886b463e7c7229e8f03",
            "user_id": "5804836",
            "role": "STD",
            "email": "dinomayer@ankunding.net",
            "firstname": "Vallie",
            "lastname": "Aufderhar",
            "classroom": "2/6",
            "number": 57,
            "school_id": "66a15336180937847c68410e",
            "send_statistic": {},
            "language": "ENG",
            "value": -1,
            "device": null,
            "notification": null,
            "created_at": "2024-07-29T13:26:30.812Z",
            "updated_at": "2024-07-29T13:26:30.812Z"
        },
        {
            "_id": "66a79886b463e7c7229e8f00",
            "user_id": "1600341",
            "role": "STD",
            "email": "simeonhilll@towne.biz",
            "firstname": "Tyrique",
            "lastname": "Bartoletti",
            "classroom": "3/4",
            "number": 85,
            "school_id": "66a15336180937847c68410e",
            "send_statistic": {},
            "language": "ENG",
            "value": -1,
            "device": null,
            "notification": null,
            "created_at": "2024-07-29T13:26:30.811Z",
            "updated_at": "2024-07-29T13:26:30.811Z"
        },
.
.
.

or this
{
            "_id": "66a79886b463e7c7229e8f06",
            "user_id": "833095",
            "role": "STD",
            "email": "dedrickstiedemann@white.biz",
            "firstname": "Alva",
            "lastname": "Nolan",
            "classroom": "1/6",
            "number": 10,
            "school_id": "66a15336180937847c68410e",
            "send_statistic": {},
            "language": "ENG",
            "value": -1,
            "device": null,
            "notification": null,
            "created_at": "2024-07-29T13:26:30.813Z",
            "updated_at": "2024-07-29T13:26:30.813Z"
        },
        {
            "_id": "66a544c33a8dff9aaaf6533f",
            "user_id": "2754050",
            "role": "STD",
            "email": "audreannelangworth@price.name",
            "firstname": "Armani",
            "lastname": "Towne",
            "classroom": "6/2",
            "number": 32,
            "school_id": "66a15336180937847c68410e",
            "send_statistic": {},
            "language": "ENG",
            "value": -1,
            "device": null,
            "notification": null,
            "created_at": "2024-07-27T19:04:35.984Z",
            "updated_at": "2024-07-27T19:04:35.984Z"
        },
        {
            "_id": "66a79886b463e7c7229e8ef5",
            "user_id": "805915",
            "role": "STD",
            "email": "kathryneratke@hahn.com",
            "firstname": "Berta",
            "lastname": "Lind",
            "classroom": "5/6",
            "number": 52,
            "school_id": "66a15336180937847c68410e",
            "send_statistic": {},
            "language": "ENG",
            "value": -1,
            "device": null,
            "notification": null,
            "created_at": "2024-07-29T13:26:30.806Z",
            "updated_at": "2024-07-29T13:26:30.806Z"
        },
.
.
.

The point is that, I already replicate the aggregate command in MongoDB Compass. The result will ALWAYS be correct no matter how many time I click.
Can golang be a problem. Like how can it be?
Thank you for helping!

It's hard to tell from the limited code here, but I am seeing a range over a map. The order of a for ... range someMap is intentionally random, you cannot rely on the order of the keys in the map:


The iteration order over maps is not specified and is not guaranteed to be the same from one iteration to the next. If a map entry that has not yet been reached is removed during iteration, the corresponding iteration value will not be produced. If a map entry is created during iteration, that entry may be produced during the iteration or may be skipped. The choice may vary for each entry created and from one iteration to the next. If the map is nil, the number of iterations is 0.


https://go.dev/ref/spec#For_statements
To iterate in a specific order, you would need to sort the entries first, and iterate over the sorted slice.

Can you specific me the code that you want to see? I can post it. Also, I have tried rearrange the map manually in MongoDB Compass. The result is still, always correct. Is there any possible problem with Mongo driver?

Please see [mcve]. Providing an example that runs in the Go playground would be easiest.
